# How to set the layout width and height in include tag in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my .xml code

```
<include layout="@layout/edit_password"
            android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"/>
```

I want to change the layout height and width dynamically of the include tag in android studio.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = passwordLayout.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 200;
            passwordLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            newPasswordLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            confirmPasswordLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is what you want, but if you need to change the tag  size by code, the simple answer is you can’t.

The include tag will be replace by the layout it points to. So that are the views you need to change.

Check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Comment: Then why is it that when I set my <include/> tag with its width and height in an .xml it works perfectly but I cant do it with java code?

Comment: Simply because the value you set on the include tag will override the size of the view it points to before inflation. After the view is created this tag no longer exists, on the layout it points to.

Comment: so there is no other way that I can resize the include tag? coz even if I resize the layout inflated, the include height and width is fix.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Can you please post the full code?

Comment: @JesusaBatoctoy If that fixed your issue, please mark this answer has it correct one so it can helper others :)